# 所定のディレクトリにnode_modulesとしてのExpressをインストールするためにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

Tags: node.js, shellscript, npm

いつもお世話になっております。
下記の質問についてご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示を願います。

---

#### 【質問の主旨】

GitHubで公開されている[advanced-interactivity-in-amp](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/advanced-interactivity-in-amp)を、Mac OSのホームディレクトリに`git clone`した後、node_modulesとして **Express** をインストールするためにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？パスの書きかえが必要が気がしますが、その内容が分かりません。

#### 【質問の補足】

1.

下記の手順でMac OSのホームディレクトリにある、[advanced-interactivity-in-amp](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/advanced-interactivity-in-amp)ディレクトリにExpressをインストールしようとしましたが、node_modulesディレクトリに含まれるはずのExpressはインストールできませんでした。

```
$ pwd
$ /Users/MYNAME
$ git clone https://github.com/googlecodelabs/advanced-interactivity-in-amp.git
$ npm install -g express-generator
/Users/MYNAME/.anyenv/envs/ndenv/versions/v8.11.3/bin/express -> /Users/MYNAME/.anyenv/envs/ndenv/versions/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express-cli.js
$ ls
CONTRIBUTING.md LICENSE     README.md   app.js      package.json    static // node_modulesがない
```

2.

`$ npm install -g express-generator`を実行するとExpressを含むnode_modulesディレクトリは下記の位置にインストールされます。

```
$pwd
/Users/MYNAME/.anyenv/envs/ndenv/versions/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/express-generator
```

3.

Node.jsの管理は[こちらのページ](https://h2ham.net/anyenv)を参考にして **anyenv** を使っています。

4.

現在のパスの設定は下記の通りです。

```
$ pwd
/Users/MYNAME
$ view .bash_profile
#!/bash/profile
export PATH=$HOME/.anyenv/bin:$PATH
eval "$(anyenv init -)"
```

5.
今回の質問に関係するツールやパッケージのバージョンは以下の通りです。

```
$ node -v
v8.11.3
$ ndenv versions
  v10.15.1
  v10.8.0
  v4.3.0
  v4.3.1
  v4.7.0
* v8.11.3 (set by /Users/MYNAME/.anyenv/envs/ndenv/version)
$ anyenv versions
ndenv:
  v10.15.1
  v10.8.0
  v4.3.0
  v4.3.1
  v4.7.0
* v8.11.3 (set by /Users/MYNAME/.anyenv/envs/ndenv/version)
rbenv:
* system (set by /Users/MYNAME/.anyenv/envs/rbenv/version)
$ npm -v
6.8.0
$ express --version 
4.16.0
```

---

以上、ご確認のほどよろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

git clone後、
1. `cd advanced-interactivity-in-amp`
2. `npm install`
で必要なモジュールが`node_modules`にインストールされます。

余談ですが、
1. `npm install`の`-g`はglobalオプションで、Node.jsで書かれたコマンド（npmなど）をインストールする場合に使います。global（今回の例ではndenv配下）にインストールされるので、カレントディレクトリに依存せずにコマンドが使えるようになります
2. `npm install`だけの場合は、カレントディレクトリの`package.json`の記述に従って、カレントディレクトリにモジュールがインストールされます。Expressは`package.json`に依存するモジュールとして記述されているので、特に指定は必要ありません

Comment: sanadan さん。
コメントありがとうございます。

```
$ cd advanced-interactivity-in-amp
$ npm install
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json...
$ ls
node_modules
```

ご指摘の通り、上記のコマンドを実行すると`node_modules`がインストールできました。また`node_modules`の中に`express`のパッケージも含まれていました。

以降は余談です。1度目にnode_modulesとしてExpressをインストールしようとしたときは、なぜか`npm install`ではエラーが出ました。そのエラーについて他の方にも質問をしていました。

そのときの経緯をこちらの[【2019年3月8日（金）作成】 Expressのインストールについて](https://hackmd.io/svJRiPt1SWyd71b3ZjrY2A)にまとめています。ご参考までにご一読いただければ幸いです。